Deck gl with Jest mock WebMercatorViewport object #8809
I'm trying to mock the object of WebMercatorViewport with the fitBounds function for my unit tests.
I'm using Jest and react-testing-library,
but I can't get rid of the error:
(intermediate value).fitBounds is not a function
TypeError: (intermediate value).fitBounds is not a function

The usage In my code is:
import { WebMercatorViewport } from "@deck.gl/core"
const webMercatorViewport = new WebMercatorViewport({ width: 600, height: 400 })
const { latitude, longitude } = webMercatorViewport.fitBounds([southWest, northEast], { padding: 30 })

In my setupTests I'm using jest mock:
  jest.mock("@deck.gl/core", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  WebMercatorViewport: jest.fn(() => ({
    fitBounds: jest.fn(),
  })),
  default: PropsViewer("DeckGL"),
}))

versions:
"deck.gl": "^9.0.9",
"react-map-gl": "^7.1.7",
"ts-jest": "29.1.2",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.17.0",
"@testing-library/react": "15.0.2",

